# Conditional Cell Formatting in KOGrid

Tags: knockout.js, single-page-application, knockout-2.0, kogrid

I am trying to change text color based on a number being positive or negative in a kogrid cell.  If the number is negative, i need the text color to be red. If the number is positive, I need the text color to be green.

I thought using the cellClass attribute of the columndefs would do the trick, but it does not seem to be working.

Here is a jsfiddle to illistrate- http://jsfiddle.net/wood0615/Bug56/10/

Here is the viewmodel code:

```
 function mainVm(){
var self = this;

this.myData = ko.observableArray([{name: "Moroni", Balance: -50000},
                                  {name: "Tiancum", Balance: 4365},
                                  {name: "Jacob", Balance: -27677},
                                  {name: "Nephi", Balance: 29676},
                                  {name: "Enos", Balance: 3489}]);


this.gridOptions = { 
    data: self.myData, 
    columnDefs: [{ field: 'name', displayName: 'Client Name', width: 140 }, 
                 { field: 'Balance', displayName: 'Balance', width: 100,
                 cellClass: function (data) { return parseFloat(data) < 0 ? "text-negative" : "text-positive" }}
                ]};
 };
```

The View code:

```
  <div class="gridStyle" data-bind="koGrid: gridOptions"></div>
```

CSS:

```
 .gridStyle {
border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
width: 400px; 
height: 300px;
}
.text-negative {
 color: #b94a48;
}
.text-positive {
 color: #468847;
}
```

Do I have the syntax wrong on the cellClass attribute perhaps?

Comment: The kogrid docs do not indicate that `cellClass` can be anything other than a string. So your function is likely not useful (even if that would be a nice feature). However, have a look at this page for an example of doing basically what you are interested in using cell templates: https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid/wiki/Cell-Template-Library

Comment: I found some confirmation of my hunch. If you inspect one of those `td` elements you'll discover it does indeed have a `class` set, but it is to the text which is the definition of your anonymous function. Basically your function was cast to a string. In this case, kogrid is not smart about interpreting strings versus functions versus observables like you might be used to with knockout's regular data-bind syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ko only takes the template as a inline string. I like to wrap this so that you only point out the template id. This can be done by creating a custom field like

```
CustomField = function(displayName, templateId) {
    this.displayName = displayName;
    this.cellTemplate = '<div data-bind="template: { name: \'' + templateId  + '\', data: $parent.entity }"></div>';
};
```

Then its just a matter of using standard KO templating

http://jsfiddle.net/Bug56/12/